# Underline text links but not buttons

Tags: css, button, underline

I am building a site that uses both text hyperlinks, as well as CSS button ones. I am trying to configure the CSS so that the text links generate an underline when hovered, but not the buttons.

I have tried a number of configurations with the *:not()* and *a* classes like `a:not(button):hover`,  `a :not(button):hover`, `a:hover :not(button)` and `a:hover:not(button)` but have only succeeded in making the buttons have underlines on hover and not the text with `a button:hover`. I need to reverse this. All I've tried underlines the buttons as well or doesn't underline the text.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure it's simple, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe create a class called underlined and add that class only to the texts?

For example

```
.underlined:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

then add the underlines class only for the texts like below:

```
<a href="link" class="underlined">text</a>
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: I appreciate the response :) I was thinking of doing that, but didn't want to create a whole class for all the text links when I could select just the buttons with 'a button:hover'. I ended up scraping the whole button class altogether and just styling the a class.